# How do I know if Odin is hang/error/stuck?

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note-3, odin

I am planning to install stock ROM on my Note 3 but, Last time I did it was longer time than Tab2.7 and my GYoung.. So I plugged the USB out and boom! Kies Error... Just tell what is the sign of Odin Freeze/hang/error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't EVER unplug your device while Odin is doing stuff. If it failed it will display an error after a little while